# Updating jars in WEB-INF\lib folder are not recognize

Tags: java, jar, jakarta-ee

I am having a problem. I replaced the old jars with my new jars in WEB-INF\lib folder. We are using Tomcat5 server. After moving my jars, I restarted the Tomcat5 server. While testing the module, it is throwing exception. Because the updated jars are not taking effect.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Are you adding the jar files to your application or to the Tomcat WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: I am creating a module to read the excel files using poi in our local server. It is working fine with updated (previous old version jars were used) jars. now i moved my changes (classes and jars) to our testing server. After moving the files and jars. it is now not working. that updated jars are not taking effect. Due to this my classes are not working.

Comment: i added the jars to my web application WEB-INF\lib folder and also to build path. its working in my local server. But only the changes what i did, when i moved to another server. there its not working. I moved the classes and jars to WEB-INF\lib folder.

Comment: Did you check `webapp` libraries are added in build path not individual jars ?

Comment: while changing any jar in WEB-INF\lib folder, why it is not reflecting also after the restart of server. It is reflecting only after the jars added to build path. Is there any alternate for this. that with out adding to build path how a jar will reflect in the application ? Please i need help.

Comment: What exception does the server throw? ideal would be sharing of full stacktrace.

Comment: I am using struts framework. I am getting a jsp error saying that xxx Method return an exception. That means in run time classes are not available. What to do ??